# Why does Resharper call this default code a compiler error (project compiles)?

Tags: c#, resharper, openxml

Resharper says, "*Cannot resolve symbol 'Model'*" and shows this hint to fix the problem in InvalidSample.cshtml:

[image]

R# places this in the "Compiler Errors" category (the solitary instance of such in my project). The code in question was created automagically/by a tool.

Why is the scaffolding code added by Microsoft unresolvable (at present), and why, if it's a compiler *error* does the project still compile?

I wonder if the DocumentFormat.OpenXML reference I added to the project is the real problem (which "rides along with" Spreadsheet Light), but if it is a clashing of classes (named "Model") between that reference and another, why does what is apparently the "wrong" one push itself to the forefront?

### UPDATE

I removed the OpenXML (and Spreadsheet Light) references from my project and, although I no longer get the hint about importing that reference in the flagged-as-unresolvable line in the .cshtml file, it still claims "Cannot resolve symbol 'Model'" and paints that word as redder than the eponymial highlights on a red-winged blackbird.